# Kendo Editor not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

I have kendoDropDown which has onChange event that appends the result to `div id=existing-translation` and the result is [this](https://i.snag.gy/H6130Q.jpg) the BODY and SIGNATURE are editable and everything works properly. The problem is when I am testing this in Internet Explorer. For some reason when I change the language in the dropdown and the new content is loaded the fields `body` and `signature` are not editable anymore.

```
$('#FromLanguageID').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Administration/EmailBodies/GetTranslation',
        data: { emailBodyId: $('#EmailBodyID').val(), languageId: $(this).val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#existing-translation').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors if/when using developer tools to view the console?

Comment: Also which version of IE are you utilizing for this testing? That may be a factor when considering older versions vs the edge version of the IE browser.

Comment: the version is 11.576 and no I do not get any. And why should I get any when everything works in Edge and Chrome

Comment: Can you provide an example of the html markup that is used for these Body & Signature fields? One other thought, have you manually attempted to execute this '/Administration/EmailBodies/GetTranslation' method passing the IDs you are using to test to verify the HTML result is generated as you expected? Perhaps the html result could have been improperly rendered?

Comment: This is the [body and signature](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivanov961/6931e9d1042a3c10a7a9b62ba618efe8/raw/2852d706cc5ba104da45be3c74c5c8de78f4fab9/body%2520and%2520signature).
I am not really sure what do you mean by execute it manually?

Comment: I mean plugging that URL into your browser to see what HTML is returned. So, imagine you are the ajax call and you take your application's url + /Administration/EmailBodies/GetTranslation&emailBodyId=x&languageId=y where x = the email body you're testing and y is the language ID you've selected, sounds like the data isn't the issue so much as how IE is rendering the HTML. Perhaps the HTML being output by this call isn't formatted as you had expected? Give it a try!! :)

Comment: I did it  `Administration/EmailBodies/GetTranslation?emailBodyId=4&lan‌​guageId=1`  and and it crashed because **languageId** can not be null so I hardcoded the Id=1 and the result was [this](https://i.snag.gy/NGlLda.jpg)

Comment: Now that you've done that, inspect the DOM of your HTML to see if there's something wrong with it? That's the direction I was hoping to have you go in, using that specific call to verify if the output is wrong in IE for some reason. Were you able to edit the fields in your partial view calling it that way? It might be something where some subtle javascript problem is preventing these fields from being edited, is it possible to simply advise your customers avoid using IE? If it works in Chrome/Firefox, perhaps you can negotiate them to stick with non-IE browsers?

Comment: Yes the fields are editable and I don't have any problems. And the rendered HTML is the same in both browsers.

Comment: Perhaps you could advise your customers that the solution is not compatible with IE then? It's a shame that viewing the partial view it works; but not when integrated with your main screen. Good luck Ivan!